# android:autoSizeTextType in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to adjust the text to always resize depending a fixed height ?

I have a column that has a fixed height and in which the text inside should always fit

```
 Column(modifier = Modifier.height(150.dp).padding(8.dp)) {
   Text("My really long long long long long text that needs to be resized to the height of this Column")
}
```

Answer (score 55):

I use the following to adjust the font size with respect to the available width:

```kotlin
val textStyleBody1 = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
var textStyle by remember { mutableStateOf(textStyleBody1) }
var readyToDraw by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Text(
    text = "long text goes here",
    style = textStyle,
    maxLines = 1,
    softWrap = false,
    modifier = modifier.drawWithContent {
        if (readyToDraw) drawContent()
    },
    onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
        if (textLayoutResult.didOverflowWidth) {
            textStyle = textStyle.copy(fontSize = textStyle.fontSize * 0.9)
        } else {
            readyToDraw = true
        }
    }
)
```

To adjust the font size based on height, play around with the `Text` composable's attributes and use `didOverflowHeight` instead of `didOverflowWidth`:

```kotlin
val textStyleBody1 = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
var textStyle by remember { mutableStateOf(textStyleBody1) }
var readyToDraw by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Text(
    text = "long text goes here",
    style = textStyle,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    modifier = modifier.drawWithContent {
        if (readyToDraw) drawContent()
    },
    onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
        if (textLayoutResult.didOverflowHeight) {
            textStyle = textStyle.copy(fontSize = textStyle.fontSize * 0.9)
        } else {
            readyToDraw = true
        }
    }
)
```

In case you need to synchronize the font size across multiple items in a list, save the text style outside of the composable function:

```kotlin
private val textStyle = mutableStateOf(MaterialTheme.typography.body1)

@Composable
fun YourComposable() {
    Text(...)
}
```

This is certainly not perfect, as it might take some frames until the size fits and the text draws finally.

Comment: ```kotlin
Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun <T> remember(calculation: () -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T)
```


```kotlin
val (textStyle, updateTextStyle) = remember { mutableStateOf(MaterialTheme.typography.body1) }
```

Comment: @Forntoh You need to lift the theme reference out of the remember invocation. Seems like this has changed since.

Comment: This solution works, but keep in mind that it doesn't work in the preview (Compose beta09). I lost 1 hour trying to figuring out why it was not rendering correctly.

Also, see @zxon response to avoid rendering text size changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, curious why soft wrap is set to false?

Comment: @RahulSainani `softWrap = false` might not be necessary in general.
In the example above, I'm scaling down ( `fontSize * 0.9` ), if text is too large. If the text would be allowed to wrap, the layout would grow in height before it would grow in width.

Comment: It gets complicated if you want to handle both cases of having to shrink or expand the text to fit. In the latter case you need to add a step to backtrack after it overflows to the last size that didn't overflow. There's probably a faster way that does something like a binary search rather than multiplying by a fraction that would take only a couple of iterations at most. I'm also experimenting with using the ratio between the font size and `size.width` in `textLayoutResult` but it's not linear so requires some heuristics.

Comment: Also this only works when you want the text to shrink to fit, not when you want it to either shrink or expand like the pre-compose `TextView` `autoSizeTextType` did.

Answer (score 44):

I built on top of [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66090448/1262089) to support other properties of Text which are also hoisted and can be used by the caller.

```
@Composable
fun AutoResizeText(
    text: String,
    fontSizeRange: FontSizeRange,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
) {
    var fontSizeValue by remember { mutableStateOf(fontSizeRange.max.value) }
    var readyToDraw by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Text(
        text = text,
        color = color,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        fontStyle = fontStyle,
        fontWeight = fontWeight,
        fontFamily = fontFamily,
        letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
        textDecoration = textDecoration,
        textAlign = textAlign,
        lineHeight = lineHeight,
        overflow = overflow,
        softWrap = softWrap,
        style = style,
        fontSize = fontSizeValue.sp,
        onTextLayout = {
            Timber.d("onTextLayout")
            if (it.didOverflowHeight && !readyToDraw) {
                Timber.d("Did Overflow height, calculate next font size value")
                val nextFontSizeValue = fontSizeValue - fontSizeRange.step.value
                if (nextFontSizeValue <= fontSizeRange.min.value) {
                    // Reached minimum, set minimum font size and it's readToDraw
                    fontSizeValue = fontSizeRange.min.value
                    readyToDraw = true
                } else {
                    // Text doesn't fit yet and haven't reached minimum text range, keep decreasing
                    fontSizeValue = nextFontSizeValue
                }
            } else {
                // Text fits before reaching the minimum, it's readyToDraw
                readyToDraw = true
            }
        },
        modifier = modifier.drawWithContent { if (readyToDraw) drawContent() }
    )
}

data class FontSizeRange(
    val min: TextUnit,
    val max: TextUnit,
    val step: TextUnit = DEFAULT_TEXT_STEP,
) {
    init {
        require(min < max) { "min should be less than max, $this" }
        require(step.value > 0) { "step should be greater than 0, $this" }
    }

    companion object {
        private val DEFAULT_TEXT_STEP = 1.sp
    }
}
```

And the usage would look like:

```
AutoResizeText(
    text = "Your Text",
    maxLines = 3,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    fontSizeRange = FontSizeRange(
        min = 10.sp,
        max = 22.sp,
    ),
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
)
```

This way I was able to set different maxLines and even have Ellipsis as overflow as the text was just too big to fit into the set lines even with the smallest size we want.

Comment: This seems to be the most reliable answer. I couldn't get the one that used ParagraphIntrinsics to actually adjust the text size. I was also able to get this to adjust text size back up if needed by making `text` the key for the remember blocks. It's a little slow, but I just adjusted my max text size down a bit to compensate.

Comment: This works well indeed, I'm trying to make it react to layout resizing... it doesn't remeasure the fontSize because readyToDraw is stuck on true, so it won't go into the measuring block. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Ι get `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.` with latest jetpack compose version :/

Comment: For some reason, the ellipses don't work for me. Do you happen to have a really low maxLines value?

Comment: @F.Mysir make sure you import the correct FontStyle and FontWeight -- I had the same problem as you and the default imports were non-compose.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. Works like a charm. Thank you

Comment: On very important ting is missing here if the text could be changing, the key for the remember:
`var fontSizeValue by remember(text) { mutableStateOf(fontSizeRange.max.value) }
var readyToDraw by remember(text) { mutableStateOf(false) }`

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all. Despite that Brian's solution does

Comment: doesn't work correct, it uses less size for text though it can fit higher size for test device

Comment: Good approach, though rather than reimplement `Text` (and all of its parameters) I would write a function just to create the necessary modifier/size/layout parts and pass that to the text. I was able to refactor this approach to the point that using it looks like this: `with(autoScalingText(14.sp..22.sp)) { Text(modifier = textModifier, fontSize = fontSizeState.value, onTextLayout = onTextLayout, ...) }`

Answer (score 22):

This is a composable based on @Brian and @zxon comments to autosize the Text based on the available width.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    text: String,
    textStyle: TextStyle,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var scaledTextStyle by remember { mutableStateOf(textStyle) }
    var readyToDraw by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Text(
            text,
            modifier.drawWithContent {
                if (readyToDraw) {
                    drawContent()
                }
            },
            style = scaledTextStyle,
            softWrap = false,
            onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                if (textLayoutResult.didOverflowWidth) {
                    scaledTextStyle =
                            scaledTextStyle.copy(fontSize = scaledTextStyle.fontSize * 0.9)
                } else {
                    readyToDraw = true
                }
            }
    )
}
```

The preview doesn't work correctly with this (at least with beta09), you can add this code to use a placeholder for the preview:

```kotlin
    if (LocalInspectionMode.current) {
        Text(
                text,
                modifier,
                style = textStyle
        )
        return
    }
```

Comment: Wrapping this in a @composable is better and easier to use . I am struggling to modify your code to size it back up if the text changes to become shorter and doesn't need to stay small. Have you tried to do it?

Comment: @las No, I didn't try that. But I think it may work if you use the `text` as the key of remember:

`var scaledTextStyle by remember(text) { mutableStateOf(textStyle) }
    var readyToDraw by remember(text) { mutableStateOf(false) }`

Comment: Instead using constant fraction `0.9` can use `result.size.width / result.multiParagraph.width`. Its because `didOverflowWidth` implementation compare `size.width` and `multiParagraph.width`. So we can calculate fraction once instead bruteforce values. Also it improves accuracy of final font size and text looks more natural.

Comment: @swap_i I've been experimenting with that but I find the ratio between the font size and size.width is not linear so it might need some fine tuning after the initial guess if it still overflows, or perhaps some heuristics to make it a tiny bit smaller to cover for that possibility in advace.

Answer (score 17):

I did something like this

```
@Composable
fun AutosizeText() {

    var multiplier by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }

    Text(
        "Some long-ish text",
        maxLines = 1, // modify to fit your need
        overflow = TextOverflow.Visible,
        style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
            fontSize = LocalTextStyle.current.fontSize * multiplier
        ),
        onTextLayout = {
            if (it.hasVisualOverflow) {
                multiplier *= 0.99f // you can tune this constant 
            }
        }
    )
}
```

you can visually see the text shrinking till it fits

Comment: This one works and is one thing I love about compose: being able to compute values that are static in xml. I used fontSize = size * 0.90f and added a check to make sure it wasn't getting too small (in my case I made sure that the multiplier wasn't < 0.1f.

Comment: The best answer! Other answers work with deffects but this one works as expected.

Comment: I get an error: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot perform operation for Unspecified type.
at androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnitKt.checkArithmetic--R2X_6o(TextUnit.kt:344)

Comment: +1 This is the best answer as it uses ``hasVisualOverflow``, allowing it to work on **more than 1 line**

Comment: What if we don't want to see the text shrinking in real time?

Answer (score 13):

This is based on Robert's solution but it works with maxLines and height constraints.

[image: AutoSize Preview]

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun AutoSizePreview1() {
    Box(Modifier.size(200.dp, 300.dp)) {
        AutoSizeText(text = "This is a bunch of text that will fill the box", maxFontSize = 250.sp, maxLines = 2)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun AutoSizePreview2() {
    Box(Modifier.size(200.dp, 300.dp)) {
        AutoSizeText(text = "This is a bunch of text that will fill the box", maxFontSize = 25.sp)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun AutoSizePreview3() {
    Box(Modifier.size(200.dp, 300.dp)) {
        AutoSizeText(text = "This is a bunch of text that will fill the box")
    }
}

@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    acceptableError: Dp = 5.dp,
    maxFontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    contentAlignment: Alignment? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
) {
    val alignment: Alignment = contentAlignment ?: when (textAlign) {
        TextAlign.Left -> Alignment.TopStart
        TextAlign.Right -> Alignment.TopEnd
        TextAlign.Center -> Alignment.Center
        TextAlign.Justify -> Alignment.TopCenter
        TextAlign.Start -> Alignment.TopStart
        TextAlign.End -> Alignment.TopEnd
        else -> Alignment.TopStart
    }
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = modifier, contentAlignment = alignment) {
        var shrunkFontSize = if (maxFontSize.isSpecified) maxFontSize else 100.sp

        val calculateIntrinsics = @Composable {
            val mergedStyle = style.merge(
                TextStyle(
                    color = color,
                    fontSize = shrunkFontSize,
                    fontWeight = fontWeight,
                    textAlign = textAlign,
                    lineHeight = lineHeight,
                    fontFamily = fontFamily,
                    textDecoration = textDecoration,
                    fontStyle = fontStyle,
                    letterSpacing = letterSpacing
                )
            )
            Paragraph(
                text = text,
                style = mergedStyle,
                constraints = Constraints(maxWidth = ceil(LocalDensity.current.run { maxWidth.toPx() }).toInt()),
                density = LocalDensity.current,
                fontFamilyResolver = LocalFontFamilyResolver.current,
                spanStyles = listOf(),
                placeholders = listOf(),
                maxLines = maxLines,
                ellipsis = false
            )
        }

        var intrinsics = calculateIntrinsics()

        val targetWidth = maxWidth - acceptableError / 2f

        check(targetWidth.isFinite || maxFontSize.isSpecified) { "maxFontSize must be specified if the target with isn't finite!" }

        with(LocalDensity.current) {
            // this loop will attempt to quickly find the correct size font by scaling it by the error
            // it only runs if the max font size isn't specified or the font must be smaller
            // minIntrinsicWidth is "The width for text if all soft wrap opportunities were taken."
            if (maxFontSize.isUnspecified || targetWidth < intrinsics.minIntrinsicWidth.toDp())
                while ((targetWidth - intrinsics.minIntrinsicWidth.toDp()).toPx().absoluteValue.toDp() > acceptableError / 2f) {
                    shrunkFontSize *= targetWidth.toPx() / intrinsics.minIntrinsicWidth
                    intrinsics = calculateIntrinsics()
                }
            // checks if the text fits in the bounds and scales it by 90% until it does
            while (intrinsics.didExceedMaxLines || maxHeight < intrinsics.height.toDp() || maxWidth < intrinsics.minIntrinsicWidth.toDp()) {
                shrunkFontSize *= 0.9f
                intrinsics = calculateIntrinsics()
            }
        }

        if (maxFontSize.isSpecified && shrunkFontSize > maxFontSize)
            shrunkFontSize = maxFontSize

        Text(
            text = text,
            color = color,
            fontSize = shrunkFontSize,
            fontStyle = fontStyle,
            fontWeight = fontWeight,
            fontFamily = fontFamily,
            letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
            textDecoration = textDecoration,
            textAlign = textAlign,
            lineHeight = lineHeight,
            onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
            maxLines = maxLines,
            style = style
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: this is very cool (like all the novel solutions in this thread!). I think it would help to mention what each while loop does though. After messing around with it locally myself I now think I understand it as the first while loop has to be run when `maxLines > 1` (possible optimisation?) so that soft-wrapping of paragraph is adhered to, and the second while loop needs to always be run regardless.

Comment: I updated the code with comments and a bug fix.

Comment: This is better than the higher voted answers since this has no visible delay.

Answer (score 9):

LAST UPDATE: 11 January 2023 v4.1 performance fine-tuning

**Turnkey solution:**

- Adjusts the text size with optimal performance by using a **binary search algorithm** to avoid unnecessary iterations.
- Very accurate
- works with **preview** and **tested** on an app with 900k+ downloads.

[image: Previews]

**Features:**

1. Best performance: Utilizes a dichotomous binary search algorithm to quickly find the optimal text size without unnecessary iterations.
2. Alignment support: Supports 6 possible alignment values through the Alignment interface.
3. Material Design 3 support.
4. Font scaling support: Changing the font scale by the user does not affect the visual rendering result.
5. Multiline Support with maxLines Parameter: AutoSizeText introduces maxLines, enabling control over the maximum number of visible lines for text within a specific space.

**Source:**

AutoSizeText.kt:

```
// LAST UPDATE: 11 January 2023 v4.1 performance fine-tuning
package com.inidamleader.ovtracker.util.compose

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraints
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.InlineTextContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.InternalFoundationTextApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextDelegate
import androidx.compose.material3.LocalContentColor
import androidx.compose.material3.LocalTextStyle
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalProvider
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.isSpecified
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalFontFamilyResolver
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLayoutDirection
import androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextLayoutResult
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.DpSize
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.LayoutDirection
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.isSpecified
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.inidamleader.ovtracker.util.compose.SuggestedFontSizesStatus.Companion.rememberSuggestedFontSizesStatus
import com.inidamleader.ovtracker.util.compose.geometry.roundToPx
import com.inidamleader.ovtracker.util.compose.geometry.toIntSize
import com.inidamleader.ovtracker.util.compose.geometry.toSp
import kotlin.math.min

/**
 * Composable function that automatically adjusts the text size to fit within given constraints, considering the ratio of line spacing to text size.
 *
 * Features:
 *  1. Best performance: Utilizes a dichotomous binary search algorithm for swift and optimal text size determination without unnecessary iterations.
 *  2. Alignment support: Supports six possible alignment values via the Alignment interface.
 *  3. Material Design 3 support.
 *  4. Font scaling support: User-initiated font scaling doesn't affect the visual rendering output.
 *  5. Multiline Support with maxLines Parameter.
 *
 * @param text the text to be displayed
 * @param modifier the [Modifier] to be applied to this layout node
 * @param color [Color] to apply to the text. If [Color.Unspecified], and [style] has no color set,
 * this will be [LocalContentColor].
 * @param suggestedFontSizes The suggested font sizes to choose from (Should be sorted from smallest to largest, not ampty and contains only sp text unit).
 * @param suggestedFontSizesStatus Whether or not suggestedFontSizes is valid: not empty - contains oly sp text unit - sorted.
 * You can check validity by invoking [List<TextUnit>.suggestedFontSizesStatus]
 * @param stepGranularityTextSize The step size for adjusting the text size.
 * @param minTextSize The minimum text size allowed.
 * @param maxTextSize The maximum text size allowed.
 * @param fontStyle the typeface variant to use when drawing the letters (e.g., italic).
 * See [TextStyle.fontStyle].
 * @param fontWeight the typeface thickness to use when painting the text (e.g., [FontWeight.Bold]).
 * @param fontFamily the font family to be used when rendering the text. See [TextStyle.fontFamily].
 * @param letterSpacing the amount of space to add between each letter.
 * See [TextStyle.letterSpacing].
 * @param textDecoration the decorations to paint on the text (e.g., an underline).
 * See [TextStyle.textDecoration].
 * @param alignment The alignment of the text within its container.
 * @param overflow how visual overflow should be handled.
 * @param softWrap whether the text should break at soft line breaks. If false, the glyphs in the
 * text will be positioned as if there was unlimited horizontal space. If [softWrap] is false,
 * [overflow] and TextAlign may have unexpected effects.
 * @param maxLines An optional maximum number of lines for the text to span, wrapping if
 * necessary. If the text exceeds the given number of lines, it will be truncated according to
 * [overflow] and [softWrap]. It is required that 1 <= [minLines] <= [maxLines].
 * @param minLines The minimum height in terms of minimum number of visible lines. It is required
 * that 1 <= [minLines] <= [maxLines].
 * insert composables into text layout. See [InlineTextContent].
 * @param onTextLayout callback that is executed when a new text layout is calculated. A
 * [TextLayoutResult] object that callback provides contains paragraph information, size of the
 * text, baselines and other details. The callback can be used to add additional decoration or
 * functionality to the text. For example, to draw selection around the text.
 * @param style style configuration for the text such as color, font, line height etc.
 * @param lineSpacingRatio The ratio of line spacing to text size.
 *
 * @author Reda El Madini - For support, contact gladiatorkilo@gmail.com
 */
@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    suggestedFontSizes: ImmutableWrapper<List<TextUnit>> = emptyList<TextUnit>().toImmutableWrapper(),
    suggestedFontSizesStatus: SuggestedFontSizesStatus = suggestedFontSizes.rememberSuggestedFontSizesStatus,
    stepGranularityTextSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    minTextSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    maxTextSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    alignment: Alignment = Alignment.TopStart,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    minLines: Int = 1,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    lineSpacingRatio: Float = style.lineHeight.value / style.fontSize.value,
) {
    AutoSizeText(
        text = AnnotatedString(text),
        modifier = modifier,
        color = color,
        suggestedFontSizes = suggestedFontSizes,
        suggestedFontSizesStatus = suggestedFontSizesStatus,
        stepGranularityTextSize = stepGranularityTextSize,
        minTextSize = minTextSize,
        maxTextSize = maxTextSize,
        fontStyle = fontStyle,
        fontWeight = fontWeight,
        fontFamily = fontFamily,
        letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
        textDecoration = textDecoration,
        alignment = alignment,
        overflow = overflow,
        softWrap = softWrap,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        minLines = minLines,
        onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
        style = style,
        lineSpacingRatio = lineSpacingRatio,
    )
}

/**
 * Composable function that automatically adjusts the text size to fit within given constraints using AnnotatedString, considering the ratio of line spacing to text size.
 *
 * Features:
 *  Similar to AutoSizeText(String), with support for AnnotatedString.
 *
 * @param inlineContent a map storing composables that replaces certain ranges of the text, used to
 * insert composables into text layout. See [InlineTextContent].
 * @see AutoSizeText
 */
@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    text: AnnotatedString,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    suggestedFontSizes: ImmutableWrapper<List<TextUnit>> = emptyList<TextUnit>().toImmutableWrapper(),
    suggestedFontSizesStatus: SuggestedFontSizesStatus = suggestedFontSizes.rememberSuggestedFontSizesStatus,
    stepGranularityTextSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    minTextSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    maxTextSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    alignment: Alignment = Alignment.TopStart,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    minLines: Int = 1,
    inlineContent: ImmutableWrapper<Map<String, InlineTextContent>> = mapOf<String, InlineTextContent>().toImmutableWrapper(),
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    lineSpacingRatio: Float = style.lineHeight.value / style.fontSize.value,
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    // Change font scale to 1F
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalDensity provides Density(density = density.density, fontScale = 1F)
    ) {
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = modifier,
            contentAlignment = alignment,
        ) {
            val combinedTextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current + style.copy(
                color = color.takeIf { it.isSpecified } ?: style.color,
                fontStyle = fontStyle ?: style.fontStyle,
                fontWeight = fontWeight ?: style.fontWeight,
                fontFamily = fontFamily ?: style.fontFamily,
                letterSpacing = letterSpacing.takeIf { it.isSpecified } ?: style.letterSpacing,
                textDecoration = textDecoration ?: style.textDecoration,
                textAlign = when (alignment) {
                    Alignment.TopStart, Alignment.CenterStart, Alignment.BottomStart -> TextAlign.Start
                    Alignment.TopCenter, Alignment.Center, Alignment.BottomCenter -> TextAlign.Center
                    Alignment.TopEnd, Alignment.CenterEnd, Alignment.BottomEnd -> TextAlign.End
                    else -> TextAlign.Unspecified
                },
            )

            val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
            val currentDensity = LocalDensity.current
            val fontFamilyResolver = LocalFontFamilyResolver.current
            val coercedLineSpacingRatio = lineSpacingRatio.takeIf { it.isFinite() && it >= 1 } ?: 1F
            val shouldMoveBackward: (TextUnit) -> Boolean = {
                shouldShrink(
                    text = text,
                    textStyle = combinedTextStyle.copy(
                        fontSize = it,
                        lineHeight = it * coercedLineSpacingRatio,
                    ),
                    maxLines = maxLines,
                    minLines = minLines,
                    softWrap = softWrap,
                    layoutDirection = layoutDirection,
                    density = currentDensity,
                    fontFamilyResolver = fontFamilyResolver,
                )
            }

            val electedFontSize = kotlin.run {
                if (suggestedFontSizesStatus == SuggestedFontSizesStatus.VALID)
                    suggestedFontSizes.value
                else
                    remember(suggestedFontSizes) {
                        suggestedFontSizes.value
                            .filter { it.isSp }
                            .takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
                            ?.sortedBy { it.value }
                    }
            }
                ?.findElectedValue(shouldMoveBackward = shouldMoveBackward)
                ?: rememberCandidateFontSizesIntProgress(
                    density = density,
                    dpSize = DpSize(maxWidth, maxHeight),
                    maxTextSize = maxTextSize,
                    minTextSize = minTextSize,
                    stepGranularityTextSize = stepGranularityTextSize,
                ).findElectedValue(
                    transform = { density.toSp(it) },
                    shouldMoveBackward = shouldMoveBackward,
                )

            Text(
                text = text,
                overflow = overflow,
                softWrap = softWrap,
                maxLines = maxLines,
                minLines = minLines,
                inlineContent = inlineContent.value,
                onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
                style = combinedTextStyle.copy(
                    fontSize = electedFontSize,
                    lineHeight = electedFontSize * coercedLineSpacingRatio,
                ),
            )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(InternalFoundationTextApi::class)
private fun BoxWithConstraintsScope.shouldShrink(
    text: AnnotatedString,
    textStyle: TextStyle,
    maxLines: Int,
    minLines: Int,
    softWrap: Boolean,
    layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
    density: Density,
    fontFamilyResolver: FontFamily.Resolver,
) = TextDelegate(
    text = text,
    style = textStyle,
    maxLines = maxLines,
    minLines = minLines,
    softWrap = softWrap,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    density = density,
    fontFamilyResolver = fontFamilyResolver,
).layout(
    constraints = constraints,
    layoutDirection = layoutDirection,
).hasVisualOverflow

@Composable
private fun rememberCandidateFontSizesIntProgress(
    density: Density,
    dpSize: DpSize,
    minTextSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    maxTextSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    stepGranularityTextSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
): IntProgression {
    val max = remember(maxTextSize, dpSize, density) {
        val intSize = density.toIntSize(dpSize)
        min(intSize.width, intSize.height).let { max ->
            maxTextSize
                .takeIf { it.isSp }
                ?.let { density.roundToPx(it) }
                ?.coerceIn(range = 0..max)
                ?: max
        }
    }

    val min = remember(minTextSize, max, density) {
        minTextSize
            .takeIf { it.isSp }
            ?.let { density.roundToPx(it) }
            ?.coerceIn(range = 0..max)
            ?: 0
    }

    val step = remember(stepGranularityTextSize, min, max, density) {
        stepGranularityTextSize
            .takeIf { it.isSp }
            ?.let { density.roundToPx(it) }
            ?.coerceAtLeast(minimumValue = 1)
            ?: 1
    }

    return remember(min, max, step) {
        min..max step step
    }
}

// This function works by using a binary search algorithm
fun <E> List<E>.findElectedValue(shouldMoveBackward: (E) -> Boolean) = run {
    indices.findElectedValue(
        transform = { this[it] },
        shouldMoveBackward = shouldMoveBackward,
    )
}

// This function works by using a binary search algorithm
private fun <E> IntProgression.findElectedValue(
    transform: (Int) -> E,
    shouldMoveBackward: (E) -> Boolean,
) = run {
    var low = first
    var high = last
    while (low <= high) {
        val mid = low + (high - low) / 2
        if (shouldMoveBackward(transform(mid)))
            high = mid - 1
        else
            low = mid + 1
    }
    transform(high.coerceAtLeast(minimumValue = first))
}

enum class SuggestedFontSizesStatus {
    VALID, INVALID, UNKNOWN;

    companion object {
        val List<TextUnit>.suggestedFontSizesStatus
            get() = if (isNotEmpty() && all { it.isSp } && sortedBy { it.value } == this)
                VALID
            else
                INVALID
        val ImmutableWrapper<List<TextUnit>>.rememberSuggestedFontSizesStatus
            @Composable get() = remember(this) { value.suggestedFontSizesStatus }
    }
}

@Preview(widthDp = 200, heightDp = 100)
@Preview(widthDp = 200, heightDp = 30)
@Preview(widthDp = 60, heightDp = 30)
@Composable
fun PreviewAutoSizeTextWithMaxLinesSetToIntMaxValue() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary) {
            AutoSizeText(
                text = "This is a bunch of text that will be auto sized",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                alignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(widthDp = 200, heightDp = 100)
@Preview(widthDp = 200, heightDp = 30)
@Preview(widthDp = 60, heightDp = 30)
@Composable
fun PreviewAutoSizeTextWithMinSizeSetTo14() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary) {
            AutoSizeText(
                text = "This is a bunch of text that will be auto sized",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                minTextSize = 14.sp,
                alignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(widthDp = 200, heightDp = 100)
@Preview(widthDp = 200, heightDp = 30)
@Preview(widthDp = 60, heightDp = 30)
@Composable
fun PreviewAutoSizeTextWithMaxLinesSetToOne() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary) {
            AutoSizeText(
                text = "This is a bunch of text that will be auto sized",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                alignment = Alignment.Center,
                maxLines = 1,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium
            )
        }
    }
}
```

DensityExt.kt:

```
package com.inidamleader.ovtracker.util.compose.geometry

import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.isSpecified
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.DpOffset
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.DpSize
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntSize
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.isSpecified

// DP
fun Density.toSp(dp: Dp): TextUnit = dp.toSp()
fun Density.toPx(dp: Dp): Float = dp.toPx()
fun Density.roundToPx(dp: Dp): Int = dp.roundToPx()

// TEXT UNIT
fun Density.toDp(sp: TextUnit): Dp = sp.toDp()
fun Density.toPx(sp: TextUnit): Float = sp.toPx()
fun Density.roundToPx(sp: TextUnit): Int = sp.roundToPx()

// FLOAT
fun Density.toDp(px: Float): Dp = px.toDp()
fun Density.toSp(px: Float): TextUnit = px.toSp()

// INT
fun Density.toDp(px: Int): Dp = px.toDp()
fun Density.toSp(px: Int): TextUnit = px.toSp()

// SIZE
fun Density.toIntSize(dpSize: DpSize): IntSize =
    IntSize(dpSize.width.roundToPx(), dpSize.height.roundToPx())

fun Density.toSize(dpSize: DpSize): Size =
    if (dpSize.isSpecified) Size(dpSize.width.toPx(), dpSize.height.toPx())
    else Size.Unspecified

fun Density.toDpSize(size: Size): DpSize =
    if (size.isSpecified) DpSize(size.width.toDp(), size.height.toDp())
    else DpSize.Unspecified

fun Density.toDpSize(intSize: IntSize): DpSize =
    DpSize(intSize.width.toDp(), intSize.height.toDp())

// OFFSET
fun Density.toIntOffset(dpOffset: DpOffset): IntOffset =
    IntOffset(dpOffset.x.roundToPx(), dpOffset.y.roundToPx())

fun Density.toOffset(dpOffset: DpOffset): Offset =
    if (dpOffset.isSpecified) Offset(dpOffset.x.toPx(), dpOffset.y.toPx())
    else Offset.Unspecified

fun Density.toDpOffset(offset: Offset): DpOffset =
    if (offset.isSpecified) DpOffset(offset.x.toDp(), offset.y.toDp())
    else DpOffset.Unspecified

fun Density.toDpOffset(intOffset: IntOffset): DpOffset =
    DpOffset(intOffset.x.toDp(), intOffset.y.toDp())
```

ImmutableWrapper.kt:

```
package com.inidamleader.ovtracker.util.compose

import androidx.compose.runtime.Immutable
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

@Immutable
data class ImmutableWrapper<T>(val value: T)

fun <T> T.toImmutableWrapper() = ImmutableWrapper(this)

operator fun <T> ImmutableWrapper<T>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = value
```

AutoSizeTextTest.kt:

```
package com.inidamleader.ovtracker.util.compose

import androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.em
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.inidamleader.ovtracker.util.compose.SuggestedFontSizesStatus.Companion.suggestedFontSizesStatus
import org.junit.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals
import kotlin.test.assertFails
import kotlin.test.assertTrue

class AutoSizeTextTest {
    @Test
    fun findElectedIndexThrowException() {
        List(size = 0) { it }.run {
            assertFails { findElectedValue { false } }
        }
        List(size = 0) { it }.run {
            assertFails { findElectedValue { true } }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun findElectedValueAt0() {
        List(size = 1) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 0,
                actual = findElectedValue { false },
            )
        }

        List(size = 1) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 0,
                actual = findElectedValue { true },
            )
        }

        List(size = 2) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 0,
                actual = findElectedValue { true },
            )
        }

        List(size = 15) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 0,
                actual = findElectedValue { true },
            )
        }

        List(size = 16) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 0,
                actual = findElectedValue { true },
            )
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun findElectedValueAt1() {
        List(size = 2) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 1,
                actual = findElectedValue { false },
            )
        }

        List(size = 2) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 1,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 1 },
            )
        }

        List(size = 15) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 1,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 1 },
            )
        }

        List(size = 16) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 1,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 1 },
            )
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun findElectedValueAt2() {
        List(size = 3) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 2,
                actual = findElectedValue { false },
            )
        }

        List(size = 14) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 2,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 2 },
            )
        }

        List(size = 15) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 2,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 2 },
            )
        }

        List(size = 16) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 2,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 2 },
            )
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun findElectedValueAt9() {
        List(size = 10) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 9,
                actual = findElectedValue { false },
            )
        }

        List(size = 14) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 9,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 9 },
            )
        }

        List(size = 15) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 9,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 9 },
            )
        }

        List(size = 16) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 9,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 9 },
            )
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun findElectedValueAt10() {
        List(size = 11) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 10,
                actual = findElectedValue { false },
            )
        }

        List(size = 14) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 10,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 10 },
            )
        }

        List(size = 15) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 10,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 10 },
            )
        }

        List(size = 16) { it }.run {
            assertEquals(
                expected = 10,
                actual = findElectedValue { it > 10 },
            )
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun suggestedFontSizesStatus() {
        assertTrue {
            listOf(1.sp, 2.sp, 4.sp).suggestedFontSizesStatus == SuggestedFontSizesStatus.VALID
        }

        assertTrue {
            listOf(2.sp, 1.sp, 4.sp).suggestedFontSizesStatus == SuggestedFontSizesStatus.INVALID
        }

        assertTrue {
            emptyList<TextUnit>().suggestedFontSizesStatus == SuggestedFontSizesStatus.INVALID
        }

        assertTrue {
            listOf(1.sp, 2.em, 4.sp).suggestedFontSizesStatus == SuggestedFontSizesStatus.INVALID
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Track update on https://gist.github.com/inidamleader/b594d35362ebcf3cedf81055df519300

Answer (score 7):

(**Works with preview**) Here's another solution using `BoxWithConstraints` to get the available width and compare it to the width that's needed to lay out the Text in one line, using `ParagraphIntrinsics`:

```
@Composable
private fun AutosizeText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
) {
    BoxWithConstraints {
        var shrunkFontSize = fontSize
        val calculateIntrinsics = @Composable {
            ParagraphIntrinsics(
                text, TextStyle(
                    color = color,
                    fontSize = shrunkFontSize,
                    fontWeight = fontWeight,
                    textAlign = textAlign,
                    lineHeight = lineHeight,
                    fontFamily = fontFamily,
                    textDecoration = textDecoration,
                    fontStyle = fontStyle,
                    letterSpacing = letterSpacing
                ),
                density = LocalDensity.current,
                resourceLoader = LocalFontLoader.current
            )
        }

        var intrinsics = calculateIntrinsics()
        with(LocalDensity.current) {
            while (intrinsics.maxIntrinsicWidth > maxWidth.toPx()) {
                shrunkFontSize *= 0.9
                intrinsics = calculateIntrinsics()
            }
        }
        Text(
            text = text,
            modifier = modifier,
            color = color,
            fontSize = shrunkFontSize,
            fontStyle = fontStyle,
            fontWeight = fontWeight,
            fontFamily = fontFamily,
            letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
            textDecoration = textDecoration,
            textAlign = textAlign,
            lineHeight = lineHeight,
            onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
            style = style
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very cool, do you know how we can achieve this for multi lines as well? For instance if I want the text to be 5 lines.
Also, maybe the fontSize should not have a default value as TextUnit.Unspecifified as it won't work without setting an initial font size, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes you're right, for multi lines I think `while (intrinsics.maxIntrinsicWidth > maxWidth.toPx() * lineNumber)` should work, but I haven't played around with that yet

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I posted a modified version that takes height and maxLines into account.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add that, if you do not want to see the middle states from the answer of @Brian, you can try this.

```
        modifier = Modifier
            .drawWithContent {
                if (calculationFinish) { // replace by your logic 
                    drawContent()
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that in @EmbMicro [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71416530/6510726) maxlines sometimes gets ignored. I fixed that issue and also replaced the deprecated call to Paragraph with `constraints` instead of `with`

```
@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    acceptableError: Dp = 5.dp,
    maxFontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
) {
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = modifier) {
        var shrunkFontSize = if (maxFontSize.isSpecified) maxFontSize else 100.sp

        val calculateIntrinsics = @Composable {
            val mergedStyle = style.merge(
                TextStyle(
                    color = color,
                    fontSize = shrunkFontSize,
                    fontWeight = fontWeight,
                    textAlign = textAlign,
                    lineHeight = lineHeight,
                    fontFamily = fontFamily,
                    textDecoration = textDecoration,
                    fontStyle = fontStyle,
                    letterSpacing = letterSpacing
                )
            )
            Paragraph(
                text = text,
                style = mergedStyle,
                spanStyles = listOf(),
                placeholders = listOf(),
                maxLines = maxLines,
                ellipsis = false,
                constraints = Constraints(maxWidth = ceil(LocalDensity.current.run { maxWidth.toPx() }).toInt()) ,
                density = LocalDensity.current,
                fontFamilyResolver = LocalFontFamilyResolver.current
            )
        }

        var intrinsics = calculateIntrinsics()

        val targetWidth = maxWidth - acceptableError / 2f

        with(LocalDensity.current) {
            if (maxFontSize.isUnspecified || targetWidth < intrinsics.minIntrinsicWidth.toDp() || intrinsics.didExceedMaxLines) {
                while ((targetWidth - intrinsics.minIntrinsicWidth.toDp()).toPx().absoluteValue.toDp() > acceptableError / 2f) {
                    shrunkFontSize *= targetWidth.toPx() / intrinsics.minIntrinsicWidth
                    intrinsics = calculateIntrinsics()
                }
                while (intrinsics.didExceedMaxLines || maxHeight < intrinsics.height.toDp()) {
                    shrunkFontSize *= 0.9f
                    intrinsics = calculateIntrinsics()
                }
            }
        }

        if (maxFontSize.isSpecified && shrunkFontSize > maxFontSize)
            shrunkFontSize = maxFontSize

        Text(
            text = text,
            color = color,
            fontSize = shrunkFontSize,
            fontStyle = fontStyle,
            fontWeight = fontWeight,
            fontFamily = fontFamily,
            letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
            textDecoration = textDecoration,
            textAlign = textAlign,
            lineHeight = lineHeight,
            onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
            maxLines = maxLines,
            style = style
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: left a comment on @EmbMicro answer that I think would also apply here :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with the following code:

```
@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    modifier: Modifier,
    text: String,
    textStyle: TextStyle,
    maxLines: Int = 1,
) {
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    var textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult? = remember { null }
    Box(modifier = modifier
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            var fontSize = textStyle.fontSize
            do {
                textLayoutResult = textMeasurer.measure(
                    text = text,
                    style = textStyle.copy(fontSize = fontSize),
                    constraints = constraints,
                    maxLines = maxLines
                )
                // fontSize = fontSize.unaryMinus()
                fontSize *= 0.95f
            } while (textLayoutResult!!.didOverflowHeight)
            val box = textLayoutResult!!.size
            layout(box.width, box.height) {
                placeable.place(0, 0)
            }
        }
        .drawWithContent {
            textLayoutResult?.let { drawText(it) }
        }) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: This may have stopped working after the 1.0.1 release....

Another way to do this inspired by @nieto's answer is to resize without recomposing by just manually measuring using the paragraph block given the inbound constraints.  Also previews correctly as a bonus

```
@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    text: String,
    style: TextStyle,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    minTextSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
) {
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier) {
        var combinedTextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current + style

        while (shouldShrink(text, combinedTextStyle, minTextSize, maxLines)) {
            combinedTextStyle = combinedTextStyle.copy(fontSize = combinedTextStyle.fontSize * .9f)
        }

        Text(
            text = text,
            style = style + TextStyle(fontSize = combinedTextStyle.fontSize),
            maxLines = maxLines,
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun BoxWithConstraintsScope.shouldShrink(
    text: String,
    combinedTextStyle: TextStyle,
    minimumTextSize: TextUnit,
    maxLines: Int
): Boolean = if (minimumTextSize == TextUnit.Unspecified || combinedTextStyle.fontSize > minimumTextSize) {
    false
} else {
    val paragraph = Paragraph(
        text = text,
        style = combinedTextStyle,
        width = maxWidth.value,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        density = LocalDensity.current,
        resourceLoader = LocalFontLoader.current,
    )
    paragraph.height > maxHeight.value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tweaked a little solution from **Thad C**

Compose version: **1.1.0-beta02**

**Preview** works

**No blinking** when text changes, text changes are handled quickly (though would be even better if text size calculation would be launched as coroutine on another thread)

```
@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    text: AnnotatedString,
    minTextSizeSp: Float,
    maxTextSizeSp: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    contentAlignment: Alignment = Alignment.TopStart,
) {
    check(minTextSizeSp > 0) { "Min text size should above zero" }
    check(minTextSizeSp < maxTextSizeSp) { "Min text size should be smaller then max text size" }
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier, contentAlignment = contentAlignment) {
        val textString = text.toString()
        val currentStyle = style.copy(
            color = color,
            fontStyle = fontStyle ?: style.fontStyle,
            fontSize = maxTextSizeSp.sp,
            fontWeight = fontWeight ?: style.fontWeight,
            fontFamily = fontFamily ?: style.fontFamily,
            textAlign = textAlign,
        )
        val fontChecker = createFontChecker(currentStyle, textString)
        val fontSize = remember(textString) {
            fontChecker.findMaxFittingTextSize(minTextSizeSp, maxTextSizeSp)
        }

        Text(
            text = text,
            style = currentStyle + TextStyle(fontSize = fontSize),
            color = color,
            textAlign = textAlign
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun BoxWithConstraintsScope.createFontChecker(currentStyle: TextStyle, text: String): FontChecker {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    return FontChecker(
        density = density,
        resourceLoader = LocalFontLoader.current,
        maxWidthPx = with (density) { maxWidth.toPx() },
        maxHeightPx = with (density) { maxHeight.toPx() },
        currentStyle = currentStyle,
        text = text
    )
}

private class FontChecker(
    private val density: Density,
    private val resourceLoader: Font.ResourceLoader,
    private val maxWidthPx: Float,
    private val maxHeightPx: Float,
    private val currentStyle: TextStyle,
    private val text: String
) {

    fun isFit(fontSizeSp: Float): Boolean {
        val height = Paragraph(
            text = text,
            style = currentStyle + TextStyle(fontSize = fontSizeSp.sp),
            width = maxWidthPx,
            density = density,
            resourceLoader = resourceLoader,
        ).height
        return height <= maxHeightPx
    }

    fun findMaxFittingTextSize(
        minTextSizeSp: Float,
        maxTextSizeSp: Float
    ) = if (!isFit(minTextSizeSp)) {
        minTextSizeSp.sp
    } else if (isFit(maxTextSizeSp)) {
        maxTextSizeSp.sp
    } else {
        var fit = minTextSizeSp
        var unfit = maxTextSizeSp
        while (unfit - fit > 1) {
            val current = fit + (unfit - fit) / 2
            if (isFit(current)) {
                fit = current
            } else {
                unfit = current
            }
        }
        fit.sp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted @biodun's solution, which is based on `onTextLayout` and `hasVisualOverflow`. I have added a minimum font size, and created a composable:

```kotlin
/**
 * This is a composable that mostly has the same API (parameters & defaults) as Text.kt,
 * just with the difference that the font size is changed to accommodate the entire text if possible.
 *
 * Note: Unfortunately this does NOT work in a preview. Previews seem to only layout the text once, and thus,
 * the fontMultiplier only gets changed to 0.95.
 */
@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    text: String,
    minFontSize: TextUnit,
    desiredFontSize: TextUnit,
    maxLines: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    minLines: Int = 1,
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
) {
    // Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68449520/3991578, added minFontSize
    var fontMultiplier by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(1f) }
    fun updateFontSize(multiplier: Float) {
        val result = desiredFontSize * multiplier
        // Make sure the font size doesn't get too small
        if (result > minFontSize) {
            fontMultiplier = multiplier
        }
    }
    Text(
        text = text,
        modifier = modifier,
        color = color,
        fontStyle = fontStyle,
        fontWeight = fontWeight,
        fontFamily = fontFamily,
        letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
        textDecoration = textDecoration,
        textAlign = textAlign,
        lineHeight = lineHeight,
        overflow = overflow,
        softWrap = softWrap,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        minLines = minLines,
        onTextLayout = {
            if (it.hasVisualOverflow) {
                updateFontSize(fontMultiplier * 0.95f)
            }
        },
        style = style.copy(
            fontSize = desiredFontSize * fontMultiplier
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Mohammad's answer.

You have to find a better way to calculate the font size by using the box's height and message's length.

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    var width by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var height by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val msg = "My really long long long long long text that needs to be resized to the height of this Column"
    Column(modifier = Modifier.height(150.dp).padding(8.dp).background(Color.Blue).onPositioned {
        width = it.size.width
        height = it.size.height
    }) {
        Log.d("mainactivity", "width = $width")
        Log.d("mainactivity", "height = $height")
        Text(
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green).fillMaxHeight(),
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = calculateFontSize(msg, height).sp),
                text = msg
        )
    }
}

fun calculateFontSize(msg: String, height: Int): Int {
    return height / (msg.length / 5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to implement autosizeable text with list of my own fonts.

So, [here is](https://gist.github.com/mzonov/77fc6de88d435704b71e8fd3194e00a6) my implementation based on Lit Climbing's answer

Answer (score 0):

**This option works in real time**.

The solution is based on the size of the container in which the text is placed. This works for both height and width.

Important details:

- `result.layoutInput.constraints.maxHeight`
- `result.layoutInput.constraints.maxWidth`
- `val localDensity = LocalDensity.current`
- `fontSize = with(localDensity) { *.toSp() }`

Solution:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.material3.LocalTextStyle
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.drawWithContent
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.TextUnit

@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
) {
    var scaledTextStyle by remember { mutableStateOf(style) }

    val localDensity = LocalDensity.current

    Text(
        text = text,
        color = color,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        fontStyle = fontStyle,
        fontWeight = fontWeight,
        fontFamily = fontFamily,
        letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
        textDecoration = textDecoration,
        textAlign = textAlign,
        lineHeight = lineHeight,
        overflow = overflow,
        softWrap = false,
        style = scaledTextStyle,
        onTextLayout = { result ->
            val scaleByHeight =
                result.layoutInput.constraints.maxHeight / 2
            val scaleByWidth =
                result.layoutInput.constraints.maxWidth / result.layoutInput.text.length
            scaledTextStyle = scaledTextStyle.copy(
                fontSize = with(localDensity) {
                    if (scaleByHeight < scaleByWidth)
                        scaleByHeight.toSp()
                    else
                        scaleByWidth.toSp()
                }
            )
        },
        modifier = modifier.drawWithContent { drawContent() }
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try BoxWithConstraints, and learn the `SubcomposeLayout` concept

```kotlin
BoxWithConstraints(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .weight(5f)
) {
    val size = min(maxWidth * 1.7f, maxHeight)
    val fontSize = size * 0.8f
    Text(
        text = first,
        color = color,
        fontSize = LocalDensity.current.run { fontSize.toSp() },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    )
}
```

Comment: This calculates the text composable with respect to the (outer) layout. But it does not take  the text itself into account. So, the text would render always with the same font size, no matter whether you have 10 characters or 100.

Comment: @Brian Yep, it's quite simple. To implement an AutoResizeTextView-ish would be more complicated.