# Jetpack Compose - TextField cuts text on the bottom

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a TextField

```
TextField(
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Search,
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onSearch = {
                onSearchTextSubmit(searchText)
            },
        ),
        modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
        singleLine = true
    )
```

the I click "Enter" on keyboard the input gets cut from the bottom.

The TextField is inside TopAppBar and I don't set any height or text size explicitly.
Is decreasing text size the only way to make it look good or there is a way to force TextField to adjust its height or text size out of the box?

Comment: you specify `singleLine = true`, so what behavior do you expect from multiline text? Maybe you just need to remove the new line characters?

Comment: I have limit for number of characters user can input so I always expect it to be 1 line. Text being cut even in case when it's 1 line. just bottom part of some characters like "j" is not visible

Comment: with adding a mutable state value to your code, all characters remain uncropped. Please provide a [minimum reproducible example].(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or at least a video

Answer (score 4):

You need to increase the height of the field by a modifier that looks like this:

```
modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp), //56 or higher!
```

Thus, todays options are:

1. Increase the height of the `TextField`
2. Decrease the size of the font

Comment: yeah I tried that. but I was thinking about something like autoTextSize

Comment: Ah, I see. I just found the post again, I read some days ago: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971569/androidautosizetexttype-in-jetpack-compose
Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the surrounding containers like Card Box Row Column you will find one with a fixed Height it has impact on your composable you should increase that height i was having the same problem i found a card with fixed height 150.dp i change it to 160.dp and it works hope its the same for you