# Jetpack Compose - Fit Text in a specific box

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How can I fit a text, inside a specific Box / Container (i.e of Size `100.dp`)

Is there a way to Fit a string inside a Box, in Compose?

Here is what I tried:

```
@Composable
fun playText() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0xFF242E38)),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xFFEEEEEE))
            .width(100.dp)
            .height(100.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "FIT ME",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .wrapContentSize(
                        Alignment.Center,
                        unbounded = true
                    )
                    .requiredSize(100.dp),
                color = Color(0xFF242E38),
                fontSize = 50.sp,
                style = TextStyle.Default.copy(
                    background = Color(0xFFEAC43D)
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun show() {
    playText()
}
```

Here is the current result:

[image: current result]

Here is the expected result (`which I achieved by decreasing the font size, just to demonstrate what is expected`):

[image: expected result]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android:autoSizeTextType in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971569/androidautosizetexttype-in-jetpack-compose)