# Adaptive letterSpacing in Text Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

How can I make letterSpacing adaptive to fill max width?

When I'm trying to set `textAlign` to `Justify` I get this:
[image]
As you see, text is not filling max width.

When I'm adding non-zero `letterSpacing` argument to `Text`, I'm getting this result:

[image]
For longer text I'm getting weird result with letter stacking on each other. So, how can I make `letterSpacing` adaptive for each width?

Code:

```kotlin
Text(text = "07:30", 
     textAlign = TextAlign.Justify, 
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
     //letterSpacing = 20.sp
)
```

Comment: Have you check answers under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971569/androidautosizetexttype-in-jetpack-compose/68258975#68258975)?

Answer (score 0):

@Pylyp Dukhov mentioned [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971569/androidautosizetexttype-in-jetpack-compose/68258975#68258975) that indirectly answers my question.
So, we need to small down `letterSpacing` when text overflows it's parent and grow up when not overflows. Seems to be not the best solution, but better than nothing.
Code:

```kotlin
var readyToDraw by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var letterSpacing by remember { mutableStateOf(50.sp) }
Text(
    text = "07:30",
    modifier = Modifier
        .drawWithContent {
            if (readyToDraw) drawContent()
        }
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    softWrap = false,
    letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
    onTextLayout = { result ->
        if (!readyToDraw) {
            if (!result.didOverflowWidth && letterSpacing < 80.sp) {
                letterSpacing *= 1.1f
                readyToDraw = true
            } else if (result.didOverflowWidth && letterSpacing > 5.sp) {
                letterSpacing *= 0.9f
            } else {
                readyToDraw = true
            }
        }
    }
)
```