How to Dynamically Resize the Item Width or the Font Size in the Item in a LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose
I am using a LazyColumn to display the name of a person in a vertical style so that it could be seen amongst the crowd easily.
But I want the font size of the characters in the list to dynamically decrease according to the height of the device so that the complete name is displayed on the screen and there should be no need to scroll the name.
I don't know whether even the approach I am using is good or not.  What would be a way to implement that?
class NameActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            ScreenShoutTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                val hexColor= intent.getStringExtra("hexColor")
                val color= Color(hexColor!!.toLong(16))
                val enteredText= intent.getStringExtra("name")
                val textList= enteredText?.toCharArray()?.map { it.toString() }?: listOf()

                LazyColumn(modifier= Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(color)
                    ,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {


                   items(textList){char->
                       Text(text = char,color=Color.Black, fontSize = 150.sp)
                   }

                    


                }

                SideEffect {
                    val window = (this as Activity).window
                    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
                    window.statusBarColor = color.toArgb()
                    window.navigationBarColor = color.toArgb()


                }
            }
        }
    }
}



@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview2() {
    ScreenShoutTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}

I expect the font size of the items in the list should dynamically decrease or increase within the height of the current device and with the maximum font size possible so that we're using maximum height of the screen to display the name.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971569/androidautosizetexttype-in-jetpack-compose

No Sir, my problem is unique !
