Overlap texts in JetPack Compose Calculator App
(https://i.sstatic.net/ittqYMvj.jpg)
I made this calculator app using JetPack Compose, but as you can see in the picture the texts are overlapping with each other. So how can i fix this?
If you want to see the app then hee is the link:-"https://github.com/subhamkumarpadhy/Calculator_ComposeApp"
I think the issue is in this code, but I don't know how to deal with it!
    @Composable
fun Calculator(
    state: CalculatorState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    buttonSpacing: Dp = 8.dp,
    onActions: (CalculatorActions) -> Unit
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(buttonSpacing)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = state.number1 + (state.operation?.symbol ?: "") + state.number2,
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 32.dp),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                fontSize = 80.sp,
                color = Color.White,
                lineHeight = 40.sp,
                maxLines = 1
            )

I am new to android development, so don't have much knowledge about how to fix this. If any one can help, it will be a pleasure.

Please [edit] and provide a [mre]. It must be directly part of the question, not a link to an external site. Also make sure to reduce your code so it only contains the parts that are necessary to demonstrate the problem, please leave out everything else, it only distracts from the actual problem.

This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971569/androidautosizetexttype-in-jetpack-compose.

It would be more helpful if you could have provided some code but based on your question, you can dynamically adjusting the font size or ensuring the text scales appropriately. Here is my solution:
@Composable
fun CalculatorText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.White,
    initialFontSize: TextUnit = 80.sp
) {
    var fontSize by remember { mutableStateOf(initialFontSize) }
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(vertical = 32.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            fontSize = fontSize,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
            color = color,
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            maxLines = 1,
            softWrap = false,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                if (textLayoutResult.didOverflowWidth) {
                    fontSize = fontSize * 0.9
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

You can now use this composable like this:
CalculatorText(
    text = hardcodedValue,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(vertical = 32.dp),
    color = Color.White,
    initialFontSize = 80.sp
)


i have added the code, now can you tell me what can I do?

A softWrap = false was missing, I just added it.
